# Problem while storing CGRect into plist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, plist, cgrect

I am trying to save an array which contains `CGRect` values. I know plists are not compatible with the `CGRect` type, so I slightly modified my code and now I am storing `NSNumber` instead of storing the rect value -- I split the rect value into four values: x, y, width, height.

```
[myArray1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:CGRectGetMinX(rawRect)]];
[myArray1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:CGRectGetMinY(rawRect)]];
[myArray1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:CGRectGetWidth(rawRect)]];
[myArray1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:CGRectGetHeight(rawRect)]];
```

Now `myArray1` contains only `NSNumber`s and I am trying to store these values into a plist, but I can't loading the values back. Can any one correct me if I am doing anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance; I'm waiting for your valuable information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
CGRect rect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 480.0f);
//you need to translate the rect into a compatible "Plist" object such as NSString
//luckily, there is a method for that

[rectArray addObject:NSStringFromRect(rect)];

//save into a plist


...
```

on retrieval of this value

```
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString([rectArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have presented looks correct.  Your issue is likely elsewhere.  It might be in the loading code, or somewhere else in the saving code, but you haven't posted anything else, so I can't be sure of where the problem lies.

You can try johnoodles approach if you like for simplicity's sake, but that will likely create a larger plist file and will also take longer to store and retrieve.  If you're storing a relatively small number of rects, it probably not a problem, but if you're storing a lot, you might notice a delay that would be much shorter if storing as actual numbers.